# Exclude a specific path from Express' all()

Tags: express

I'm using the following to check for privileges on every request to my server:

```
 app.all('*',users.authCheck);
```

However, i wish to disable this for one specific request, namely the login route:

```
app.post('/users/login', users.login);
```

I know that i could move all my routes into another directory and change to `app.all('foobar/*',users.authCheck);`

However, i would rather like to exclude one route.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a if to your route:

```
// Somewhere in your app
users.authCheck = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url === '/users/login') {
    return;
  }
};
```

That's not the best solution, however will help you for now.